# Set decimals to specific values

Tags: c#, decimal, math.round

I'm working on a program that will calculate the change based on users input of price and amount paid. I shall then print the change to console followed by the amount of different bills and coins. This is all good until the final part, we are using 50-cents (halfCrown) in code. If the change is <0.25 i shall set the change to 0, if it's >0.25, <0.75 the change should be set to 0.5, if it's >0.75 it should be 1. My question is, how do I do this, I've browsed multiple forums for answers but haven't got anything to work.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Diagnostics.Eventing.Reader;
using System.Linq;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Inlämningsuppgift_1__Växel
{
    internal class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            // Meddelande som välkomnar användaren.
            Console.WriteLine("Hej och välkommen till kassan, jag ska nu hjälpa dig att beräkna din växel!");

            // Deklarerar variablerna jag ska använda. Vissa har double då jag de ska kunna behandla decimaler. Int för de som är heltal
            double price;
            double paidAmount;
            double change;
            int thousandBills;
            int fiveHundredBills;
            int hundredBills;
            int fiftyBills;
            int twentyBills;
            int tenCrowns;
            int fiveCrowns;
            int oneCrown;
            double halfCrown;
           
            Console.Write("Mata in varans pris: "); // Ber användaren att mata in pris för varan.
            price = Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine()); // Gör om användarens svar från string till double.
            Console.Write("Mata in ditt betalade belopp: "); // Ber användaren mata in betalat belopp.
            paidAmount = Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine()); // Gör om användarens svar från string till double.
            change = paidAmount - price; // Tilldelar variablen "change" genom att subtrahera betalade beloppet från priset.
            Console.WriteLine("Din växel är: " + change + "kr"); // Skriver ut växeln användaren får med hjälp av variabeln "change".

            
            
            
                thousandBills = (int)change / 1000;
                change = change % 1000;
                Console.WriteLine("Antal 1000-sedlar: "+ thousandBills); // Skriver ut antal 1000-sedlar till konsolen.

                fiveHundredBills = (int)change / 500;
                change = change % 500;
                Console.WriteLine("Antal 500-sedlar: " + fiveHundredBills); // Skriver ut antal 500-sedlar till konsolen.

                hundredBills = (int)change / 100;
                change = change % 100;
                Console.WriteLine("Antal 100-sedlar: " + hundredBills); // Skriver ut antal 100-sedlar till konsolen.

                fiftyBills = (int)change / 50;
                change = change % 50;
                Console.WriteLine("Antal 50-sedlar: "+ fiftyBills); // Skriver ut antal 50-sedlar till konsolen.

                twentyBills = (int)change / 20;
                change = change % 20;
                Console.WriteLine("Antal 20-sedlar: " +  twentyBills); // Skriver ut antal 20-sedlar till konsolen.

                tenCrowns = (int)change / 10;
                change = change % 10;
                Console.WriteLine("Antal 10-mynt: " +  tenCrowns); // Skriver ut antal 10-kronor till konsolen.

                fiveCrowns = (int)change / 5;
                change = change % 5;
                Console.WriteLine("Antal 5-mynt: " + fiveCrowns); // Skriver ut antal 5-kronor till konsolen.

                oneCrown = (int)change / 1;
                change = change % 1;
                Console.WriteLine("Antal 1-mynt: " +  oneCrown); // Skriver ut antal 1-kronor till konsolen.

                
                if (change < 0.25)
                {
                    change = 0;
                    
                }
                else if (change > 0.25 && change < 0.75)
                {
                    change = 0.5;
                }
                else 
                {
                            change++;
                }

                }
                
                change = Math.Round(change * 4, MidpointRounding.ToEven) / 4;
                halfCrown = (double)change * 2;
                change = change % 0.5;
                Console.WriteLine("Antal 50-öre: " + halfCrown); // Skriver ut antal 50-ören till konsolen.

            
            // Försökt att få in dessa på lämpliga ställen men inte kommit fram till ett lyckat resultat.
            // change = Math.Round(change * 4, MidpointRounding.ToEven) / 4;
            // change = Math.Round(change * 2.0d / 2.0d);
            Console.ReadLine();
            

        }

    }
}
```

I've tried the last if loop and other code down below that but nothing works.

Comment: First, don't use `double`, use `decimal` instead. Double is less exact than decimal (which is designed for money, not scientific calculations or speed)

Comment: `double` is a Base-2 floating point type but not the same thing as the `Decimal` type, which is a Base-10 floating point.  Change your `double` to be `Decimal`.

Comment: Is your code working? If not, what is your problem? Of there's some inexactitude, try changing everything to `decimal` first (when you are finished search your code for "double", it should not appear)

Comment: My code is working until the last part where I want the program to Round up to either 0, 0.5 or 1 whole number. For example: Lets say the user inputs price: 30.4 and paid amount: 35. The console prints out that the change is 4.6 instead of rounding it to 4.5. It also prints halfcrowns to 1.200000002

Comment: Is it your intention to evaluate 0.25. to 1.25 or will you downgrade 0.25 to 0?
I think  "if (change =< 0.25)" is the better one.

Comment: Okay, changing double to decimal solves your problem. But I think it will be better to transform the input fields price and paidAmount to öre (multiply with 100) and use int as datatype. Integer-Arithmetic will be your friend. See e.g. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-precision_floating-point_format why double cacluates so strange decimal places.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What about this:

```
change = Math.Round(change * 2) / 2;
```

Comment: Got it working now, thanks a lot! How would you explain this in a simple way what this does? I mean I get that it rounds the change and then multiplies by two and then divides by two. But why wouldn't change = Math.Round(change * 1); work? Which technically would give the same answer to the change

Comment: But you still want t to work in `decimal` and not `double`. Using ` double will eventually bite you in the ... It may be the reason you are seeing what you are seeing

Comment: Math.round rounds off to the nearest integer.  So you double whatever your value is first then round to the nearest integer.  Then divide that value by 2.  So for example if you had 0.2 -> becomes 0.4 -> rounds to 0 -> divides by 2 = 0.  If you had 0.34 -> becomes 0.68 -> rounds to 1 -> divides by 2 = 0.5.  And so on.  (but others are right that you should probably be using a Decimal type also.)

Comment: @Sand: you said _"Got it working now, thanks a lot"_. The right way to do that on this site is to upvote and/or accept Grant's answer